# How do you make the filter_tag on the Vimeo api AND the filters instead of OR?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

When I run this, and add more filters, instead of narrowing, it expands, basically saying whether a video has filter A or filter B instead of filter A and filter B

Tried looking on API and couldn't find anything

Comment: Which API endpoint are you using?

Comment: GET/users/{user_id}/projects/{project_id}/videos This one!

Comment: @NickODell and this was the docs I was referring to: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/folders#get_project_videos

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_videos. There are two parameters `filter_tag` and `filter_tag_all_of`.
First one works like filter with logical OR and seconds like filter ALL.